# Wordpress database issues - menu not saving correctly, media thumbnails not showing

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I am having a problem with Wordpress that I have not ever seen before. I when make changes to any of the menus on my site, they don't save correctly. For instance, I will add a page to the menu, and upon saving, it will be changed to a Custom Link, and it's title will be deleted.

Also, my media items are not saving correctly. In the media library, the thumbnails are not being loaded and the images won't display on the front end.

I have narrowed this down to being a database issue. Going through the process of de-activating plugins and changing themes did not resolve this behavior, but reverting to an older database did. I have already used myPhpAdmin's repair database and optimize database functions, and neither detected any issues. Are there any other known processes to help diagnose database issues?

Please let me know if I can provide any other helpful information.

Comment: Did you try to update wordpress once?

Comment: @PatrickdeFreitas yes wordpress is fully up to date. As are all of the plugins I'm using

Comment: Is there any log in php file or debug mode, I never seen this before as well, sometime cache does something like that, you are using online ambient or localhost?

Comment: unfortunately no. I have debug on but no errors are displaying. The error_log file in my home directory also has not recent errors. I am using localhost. like I said, I believe that there is an error in my database somewhere, since changing the other variables (theme, plugins) was did not effect this issue, but replacing the database did